# How do I show the top ten tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, acts-as-taggable

I have an app with Tags and it works great, but I was wondering if there was a way to restrict the tag cloud to only the MOST POPULAR tags?

Right now it looks like it's ordering my cloud by the order in which the tags were created and I have a limit of ten in in my tags_count method inside my MODEL.

I used "[Tagging](http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging)" to do it from scratch, and I am not using `acts_as_taggable`.

Controllers:

```
class DailypostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @dailyposts = Dailypost.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @dailyposts = Dailypost.all
    end
  end

end
```

Models:

```
class Dailypost < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessible :title, :content

  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings

  def self.tagged_with(name)
    Tag.find_by_name!(name).dailyposts
  end

  def self.tag_counts        ##Added a limit here
    Tag.select("tags.id, tags.name,count(taggings.tag_id) as count").
      joins(:taggings).group("taggings.tag_id, tags.id, tags.name").limit(10) 
  end

  def tag_list
    tags.map(&:name).join(", ")
  end

  def tag_list=(names)
    self.tags = names.split(",").map do |n|
      Tag.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
    end
  end

end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :dailypost_id, :tag_id

  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :dailypost
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :dailyposts, through: :taggings
end
```

Views:

```
  <div id="tag_cloud">
    <% tag_cloud Dailypost.tag_counts, %w[s m l] do |tag, css_class| %>  ###Change is here
      <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), class: css_class %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Application helper:

```
def tag_cloud(tags, classes)
  max = 0
  tags.each do |t|
    if t.count.to_i > max
      max = t.count.to_i
    end 
  end
  tags.each do |tag|
    index = tag.count.to_f / max * (classes.size - 1)
    yield(tag, classes[index.round])
  end
end
```

Comment: A hint would be in `@dailyposts = Dailypost.tagged_with(params[:tag])`. Your database understands how to sort by fields, and it knows how to `limit` (hint, hint) the number of rows returned. Active Record knows how to tell it how to do those things.

Comment: @theTinMan So i added a method to help me with this and used (:tags, :limit => 10, :order => "count desc") as suggested. But I get an error. Any idea why this may happen.

Comment: Um... I have no idea. I can't see the error on your screen.

Comment: @theTinMan Finally got it. I added a limit to my method inside my Models. and it limited the tags to 10. But i want to show the top ten. Any ideas?

Comment: Your order-by clause will sort, so do a descending sort, grab the first ten, and you're done. If it's not sorting right then your probably not sorting on the correct field.